# My PyQtGraph code can run with PyQt5, but not

Tags: python, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I am trying to make program with PyQtGraph and Qt designer.
My code can run in PyQt5 as expected.
But with PySide2, my code plot the a line outside the plot area.

This is the screenshot of the matter:
[image: This is the screenshot of the matter]
I'm using Qt Designer to make .ui.
And this is my code made by pyuic5, qtGraphTestQt5.py.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 606)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 420, 251, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 410, 251, 111))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 511, 192))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked['bool'].connect(MainWindow.slot1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

And, this is my main code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
from qtGraphTestQt5 import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        
        self.umw = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.umw.setupUi(self)
    
    def slot1(self):
        print("slot1")
        # plot data: x, y values
        crvItem = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.umw.graphicsView.addItem(crvItem)
        
        # plot y = x^2
        crvItem.xData = np.array(range(100))*0.1
        crvItem.yData = crvItem.xData**2

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app==None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does anyone have any knowledge on the matter?

Comment: How have you tried to fix it so far? What happened? Please include your debugging attempts

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem, if I change PyQt5 to PySide2 in both files I get an adequate response

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, WBM and eyllanesc.

Comment: When I run this code, no error is output. And now I am trying to change PyQt5 code to PySide as ellyansec said.Please allow time for reply.

Comment: I used anaconda-prompt, But I found that spyder output a error..Is it fatal error?

Comment: TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(PlotWidget)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)